# Accessing IFRAME content in subdomain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a domain say

```
http://www.domain.com
```

and I have subdomain

```
http://support.domain.com
```

I load `support.domain.com` in an IFRAME in `domain.com`
I was hoping

```
var ifr = document.getElementById( yourIframeId );
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var theForm = ifrDoc.getElementById( yourFormId );
```

this code to work properly. But it is not.

My question is should my subdomain be `domain.com/support`
or is there any way I can work with `support.domain.com`

Please avoid giving answers in jQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add this near the top of the outermost HTML file, it might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.domain = 'domain.com';</script>
```

---

Do you control both domains or do you control the content served from both domains?

Comment: :-( nope this does not help, still get permission denied to access while to access the iframe content

Comment: Try putting this in both documents, if you have control of both of them.